# Execute everything inside catch statement without throwing futher errors

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code where I try to sign many delegates at once but in case any of them is null I have to unsign all others.

```
try
{
    this.var1.asdf += ...

    this.var2.asdf += ...

    this.var3.asdf += ...

    this.var4.asdf += ...

    //and so on
}
catch
{
    try {
    this.var1.asdf -= ...
    }catch{}

    try{
    this.var2.asdf -= ...
    }catch{}

    try{
    this.var3.asdf -= ...
    }catch{}

    //and so on
}
```

How do I avoid all those try catch inside the big catch? I also do not want to use "if not null statements". I want to proceed over all the delegates inside catch block no matter if they might throw null reference exceptions. All lines need to be executed inside catch block.

Is there a way to tell catch to not throw any futher errors and run all its code?

Comment: I would check for null values rather than relying on exceptions.

Comment: I would like to avoid 10-20 different if statements..

Comment: This is a code smell to me. There must be a whole other way to achieve this. Can you tell us more about your use case?

Comment: 10-20 different variables with name like var1..var20 is an obvious bad pattern. Can't you use list or array for those variables ? Then use for loop to check for null and then assign your delegates ?

Comment: @devhedgehog: I've updated my answer to suggest an alternative to exceptions - but still using an extension/lambda approach to do your null check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there isn't, I normally write a try function if I need to do something and ignore the result. It's not best practise to ignore exceptions, but I understand sometimes it is acceptable to do so:

```
public T Try(Action<T> action)
{
   try 
   {
      return action();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   { 
       // Log the exception so you're at least aware of it
   }
}
```

You can then call it along the following lines:

```
Try(() => { var1.asdf.DoSomething(); });
```

---

Having read one of your comments, this might be another approach that doesn't use exceptions:

```
public static void IfNotNull(this T value, Action<T> action)
{
   if(value != null)
      action(value);
}
```

Then instead you can call, this makes it nice and clean to do the null check in your code and prevents any exceptions (which are quite slow by the way)

```
var1.IfNotNull(v => v.asdf.DoSomething());
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution.

Comment: @NikolayKostov Thanks :) I've used it in a few places - typically I'll log something out noting that the action failed but not block execution from continuing. Useful for operations such as trying to delete a file that's not used anymore etc.

Comment: This is really elegant! I have to keep this in mind!

Comment: Nice solution. Is there some kind of keyword similar to catch just that it wont throw any errors to outside. try {...} trap {.. } well trap was just an example but you get my point

Comment: @devhedgehog: Once the error is caught it will stay there and not propagate the stack - so `catch` does exactly what you're saying. It's only if you `throw` or `throw ex` within the `catch` that the errors will propagate up the stack to the calee's.

Comment: It's crazy the OP doesn't want to put `if (var1 != null) var1.asdf -= ...;` because there'll be 20 if statements, but they are happy to put `Try(() => var1.asdf -= ...);` 20 times!

Comment: @weston: Yeah it is a little, but without understanding the full situation + seeing actual code you can't always tell. However my answer fits the title really nicely - so will hopefully help other people which is what I'm punting for :)

Answer (score 1):

Base on @lan response, without anonymous method :

```
try
{
    this.var1.asdf += var1OnAsdf;

    this.var2.asdf += var2OnAsdf;

    this.var3.asdf += var3OnAsdf;

    this.var4.asdf += var4OnAsdf;

    //and so on
}
catch
{
    TryUnregister(this.var1, var1OnAsdf);
    TryUnregister(this.var2, var2OnAsdf);
    TryUnregister(this.var3, var3OnAsdf);

    //and so on
}

void TryUnregister(VarType var, DelegateType d)
{
    if (var == null) return;
    var.asdf -= d;
}
```